# What prerequisites are there to insert an Excel object into another type of document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, embedding, ole

I have Excel 2016 installed. Is there any additional package or add-on I need to make it available to other software that supports OLE?

I tried to insert an Excel spreadsheet object into Wordpad, but Excel doesn't show up on the list of available objects (I confirmed that it does on co-workers' computers). The CAD Software I use is designed to function with embedded excel spreadsheets, so I need to get this to work to get the most out of that software.

Comment: Wordpad has intentionally limited functionality, so it's a bit surprising that it would take an Excel OLE object. If you do not have access to MS Office with Word, then you might try free LibreOffice or Open Office Writer, which *can* embed objects.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, that was my initial reaction, also, but the OP indicates that this works on other computers.  (I don't have ready access to Wordpad or Excel, so can't investigate.)